# Angular material insert html string

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

Is there a way i can insert a whole html string from typescript for example:

I need this as each time info is of a different HTML type

```
 const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
     {
    position: 1,
    info: '<span class="colorMe"> {{information}} </span>', 
    
  },
 {
    position: 2,
    info : '<img [src]="element.imageUrl" />', 
    
  },
  ...
];`

And html:
<td mat-cell 
  *matCellDef="let element">{{element.info}}
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this:
`<div [innerHTML]="element.info"></div>`

maybe you need to sanitize your HTML first

Comment: it will be sanitized anywy.

Comment: It shows {{information}} instead of showing its value. ( I tried with sanitization as well)

Comment: it's working with modification in assigning values to table `<img src="${this.url}">` and `The size is ${ this.information }`